# How to Group By This Comma-Delimited Data

Tags: mysql

I have data like this :

```
ID  Book    Author
1   Book A  Andy, Brian
2   Book B  Andy, Charlie
3   Book C  Brian
```

How to group by the data so i can get like this:

```
Author  Count
Andy    2
Brian   2
Charlie 1
```

Comment: Your tables should be normalised. Create a table of authors and a table of books, and link the two using PKs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: You should normalize your data model and not try to build your own mini-database inside the 'Author' column. Once you've done that, you can use an ordinary query to count.

Comment: that's not the actual data or table i created. after some queries i get data like that. now i am confuse how to group by the data. it's still possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume you have a normalized structure, you simply need to :

```
SELECT a.author, count(*) 
FROM books b
INNER JOIN author a ON a.author_id=b.author_id
GROUP BY a.author
```