# show multiple items based on submitted id?

Tags: php, mysql, select

hope someone can help me out here. I have the following structure in my database.

```
id   nav      title   content                      date
1    2,3      nav a   askdajsdjasdasdfajsdfasd     12 june, 2012
2    2,40     nav e   askdajsdjasdasdfajsdfasd     12 june, 2012
3    12,3,14  nav b   askdajsdjasdasdfajsdfasd     12 june, 2012
4    3,4      nav c   askdajsdjasdasdfajsdfasd     12 june, 2012
```

my question is, how do I display items based on the nav id that I submit??? eg if I want to display all items (nav a, nav e) when I submit nav id 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to Group By This Comma-Delimited Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146315/how-to-group-by-this-comma-delimited-data) (unanswered)

Comment: the underlying problem is the same. It's exactly the same kind of problem that you need to solve. Rajan already gave the answer to it, the comment in the duplicate is interesting, too: Data Normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2,nav)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE nav LIKE '2,%'
OR nav LIKE '%,2'
OR nav LIKE '%,2,%'
OR nav = '2'
```

But first one is much batter.

Comment: Docs are here: [`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: just for being sure... Have you replaced the table name with the one you want?

Comment: First all storing comma separated values in table is not at all good, rather it is batter to store these values in to another table.

Comment: @JaySmoke: This works like a charm, you must have made some error by typing it in or copying it over: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7128e/1

Comment: nice one @RajanRawal thanx a mil! I now have another dilemma though, how can I retrieve the id that's been queried from the nav? Am able to use implode(",", explode(",", $row["nav"])); to get the arrays. How do I retrieve each integer from the array?

Comment: what you want to say bro? I am not getting you. Using `implode(",", explode(",", $row["nav"]));` in turn does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that X is your desired nav id, so you may want to use this query:

```
SELECT title FROM table WHERE nav REGEXP '([0-9]+,)*X(,[0-9]+)*';
```

Comment: this also works. Which of the two is safer and easier to use though?

Comment: I think this is cleanest & easiest way!

Answer (score 0):

If the nav column values range from 0 to 9 i.e. single digit like the ones presented in your example then you can safely use the following:

```
select * from table where nav like '%2%'
```

If you have values larger than 9 i.e. 10 onwards and the data can be 2,5,10,123 then you will need to create a stored procedure and pass the query value to it as parameter. This SP will then create a cursor and loop through the result set and using string functions check for the existence of the number and return the row as result if found.

The other way out, is to get the result in a PHP result object and then loop through the result rows and check for the existence of the parameter value. However, if you have several rows in the table then the SP way is much better and efficient.